# reCAPTCHA v2 for Joomla 2.5

Tags: captcha

Does anyone know a way to use reCAPTCHA v2 (as v1 is depricated and can't be used anymore) on Joomla 2.5 Contact Forms?

I even added the `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>` in my website, but nothing.
I can't upgrade joomla to another version, but I can install other plugin, if any work.

Thanks.

Comment: @Marco Balestra I can confirm, Your fix works very well, just as you mention it's necessary to generate new recaptcha keys for v2.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue and suddenly also v1 stopped working before March 31st.

I wrote a fix for Joomla 2.5 v1 ReCaptcha Plugin, that seems to work...
Download the fix: http://altersoftware.it/recaptcha.php.zip

Expand it, and use its content to replace content of original file *your-site-root*/plugin/captcha/recaptcha/recaptcha.php

According to big G's documentation it should keep working also after March 31st, given that you use valid v2 keys.

[Edit] a page for the fix: http://altersoftware.it/products/contrib/joomla25_captcha_v2

HTH

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working for me.  When I load the page using this, it throws errors.  Popup shows "The page at http://joomlatest.mysite.com says:  Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again.  "  The reCAPTCHA dialog box on the site shows"  "ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key"  . They keys that I am using are the same as on the current live site, and worked on the test site before I installed this php form.  I'm hoping this solution will be my salvation, so if you have any suggestions, kindly share them.

Comment: So far more than one hundred sites started using this patch, and you're the first reporting an issue... Apparently the issue is with the keys.
My suggestion is to generate brand new keys and ensure they match the domain. The last point seems to be crucial, given that apparently you're using a test domain other than the production site.

*EDIT* there is also another option to create a conflict that lays down the plugin: if you use more than one ReCaptcha plugin/mechanism at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the old keys you've generated for reCAPTCHA v1 - it should still work.
If you generate new keys - they won't.

Comment: That's the problem. Only those who had generated an old key can still use the reCAPTCHA v1. New users can only generate the v2.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are with the same problem, I resolved mine using an extension called 'EXT Simple Contact Form'. I download it on: http://www.ext-joom.com/en/extensions/ext-simple-contact-form-module.html

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Joomla 2.5 plugin to support the Google reCaptcha v2 widget. Don't get stuck March, 31 when Google's v1 API shuts down!
https://simplifyyourweb.com/documentation/topics/844-google-recaptcha-v2-for-joomla-2-5